How make function with await page.click, page.waitForSelector etc
In main code i use many times this fragment:
(async() => {
(somethning code)

try {
        await page.waitForSelector('.css123', {timeout: 5000});
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    
    try {
        await page.click('.css123');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

(somethning code)
}

How correctly declare this code in function and use this function in main code? I try over "const save = async() => {}" and "function save() {}" - its dont work.
update. I dont write 'page' in 'const save = async (page)'. Now its work.

What do you mean by "its dont work" exactly? Do you get a specific error or underirable behavior? const save = async() => {} is a totally correct async function signature, and function save() {} is only missing async function save() {}.

There are two ways to declare a function, and you've already mentioned them..
const myFunc = () => {} and function myFunc() {}
// Define the function
const save = async (page) => {
    try {
        await page.waitForSelector('.css123', { timeout: 5000 });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    
    try {
        await page.click('.css123');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

// Call the function in your main code
(async () => {
    // (some code)
    
    // Ensure `page` is passed to the `save` function
    await save(page);
    
    // (some other code)
})(); // auto-invoked function

Maybe you made a mistake with async

I dont write 'page' in 'const save = async (page)' -  'const save = async ()'. Now its work.
